# How to add or adjust the configuration of the file supplier in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Spring Cloud Stream's file-supplier dependency includes `FileSupplierConfiguration` which configures a File message source (from Spring Integration). I need to customize the `FileReadingMessageSource` that this @Configuration provides, but I'm not sure of the best way to do so. It provided only basic properties to control its `@Bean`s, but I need more.

I considered excluding `FileSupplierConfiguration` from the app, but I'd then have to copy most of the code from it into my own @Confguration class. Obviously that's a less than ideal solution.

So how can I customize the File message source, for example with additional `FileListFilter`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `BeanPostProcessor` @Bean, like this:

```java
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor inboundFileAdaptorCustomizer() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec) {
                 //add filter function here
                ((FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec) bean).filter(files -> ...);
            }
            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it can only do very limited customization of the resulting `FileReadingMessageSource`. That's because `FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec` is quite limited. For one thing, it only allows you to set a single additional filter. It also always uses a `CompositeFileListFilter` while in some cases I might want to use a `ChainFileListFilter` instead. The real problem is how limited the spec class is. I'm looking for an alternative that allows me full control over the underlying `FileReadingMessageSource`.

Comment: As commented in [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues/195) I was able to work-around some short-term need by constructing a `ChainFileListFilter` and using that in `spec.filter(...)`. But there is a general need to customize the `FileReadingMessageSource` that hopefully will be provided via the GitHub issue.