# How to use WatchServiceDirectoryScanner with Spring Cloud Stream file supplier?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure SpCS's file supplier to monitor a directory and publish messages when files are created or modified. Based on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69442462/639520), I have the following custom config for the `FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec` bean:

```java
@Bean
public BeanPostProcessor inboundFileAdaptorCustomizer() {
    return new BeanPostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {

            if (bean instanceof FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec) {
                FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = (FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec) bean;
                spec.get().setDirectory(properties.getDirectory());
                spec.autoCreateDirectory(false);
                spec.useWatchService(true);
                spec.watchEvents(WatchEventType.CREATE, WatchEventType.MODIFY);
                spec.preventDuplicates(false);  // We use a custom duplicates filter, see below

                spec.nioLocker();

                spec.filter(fileFilters());
            }

            return bean;
        }
    };
}
```

When I run with this config, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WatchService hasn't been started
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource$WatchServiceDirectoryScanner.listEligibleFiles(FileReadingMessageSource.java:466) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:90) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:375) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.doReceive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:349) ~[spring-integration-file-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
```

Using breakpoints I've noticed that the start() method of the `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` is never called. Instead, `doReceived()` and hence `listElibibleFiles()` is called before it's ever started, which is where the exception is coming from.

Why is SI telling the scanner to list files before it's even been started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the `FileSupplierConfiguration` - the call to `start()` is missing. The fix is [already merged](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/pull/205), but in the meantime, the workaround is like this:

```
@Bean
public SmartLifecycle fileReadingStart(FileReadingMessageSource fileMessageSource) {
    return new SmartLifecycle() {

        @Override
        public int getPhase() {
            // Make sure this runs as early as possible
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        @Override 
        public void start() {
            fileMessageSource.start();
        }

        @Override 
        public void stop() {
            fileMessageSource.stop();
        }

        @Override 
        public boolean isRunning() {
            return false;
        }
        
    };
}
```

Comment: Great, that workaround seems to work. Two questions: A) Is the missing call to start() being tracked in a GitHub issue (so that I can follow it and update our app when it's fixed)?  B) Is `fileMessageSource.stop()` also missing and need to be called from the anonymous lifecycle above?

Comment: Yes, I will track it with the issue I've mentioned in my answer. Yes, add that `stop()` delegation to the workaround.

Comment: This solution seemed to work, but we are still seeing occasional "The WatchService hasn't been started" errors on startup of the app, both for some developers locally and on our RedHat servers. When it happens, it seems that a simple restart will usually work. But is there a subtle timing bug going on even with the `SmartLifecycle` workaround?

Comment: See `SmartLifecycle.getPhase()`. You probably need to override it and return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to make this `fileReadingStart` bean to be started as early a possible.

Comment: Here is an out-of-the-box fix though: https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/pull/205

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the extra workaround code and refer to the actual fix merge.